# No option available to use .Net Core 3.0 in VS 2019 Preview

Tags: asp.net-core, visual-studio-2019, .net-core-3.0, asp.net-core-3.0

I want to use the .Net Core 3.0 preview in VS 2019 preview 2.0 but the option is not available anywhere.

I got a new computer and had to re-install the .Net Core 3.0 SDK Preview 6 and VS 2019 Preview 2 builds but the option to enable the  usage of .Net Core 3.0 preview framework does not show up anywhere in the options.

I looked in both the previous ".Net Core" and "Preview Feature" section and the option is just not there. It's like VS does not recognize the .Net Core 3.0 is installed at all.

I tried uninstalling and reinstalling everything, in any imaginable combination, with and without reboot between each. And nothing works. I assumed there was just a problem with the version so I tried with SDK Preview 5 and the option is still not showing up. Unfortunately, I don't know how to get the Preview 1 build of VS to troubleshoot.

I also made sure to check in the old ".Net Core" options and the new "Preview feature" option panels.

Comment: Why dont you install the released vs 2019?

Comment: Your question isn't really clear, but it sounds like you're looking for some kind of toggle to "turn on" .NET Core 3.0 support. No such thing exists. VS will simply utilize the latest installed .NET Core SDK version, or whatever is set in global.json. In other words, if you install .NET Core 3.0 SDK preview, then VS will automatically use that unless told otherwise (via a global.json), as it will obviously be the latest SDK.

Answer (score 1):

### In Visual Studio 2019

You can use preview versions of the .NET Core SDK by:

TOOLS -> OPTIONS -> Projects and Solutions -> .NET Core

Check the box labelled "Use previews of the .NET Core SDK"

[image]

### In Visual Studio 2019 PREVIEW (both 1 and 2)

This is not an option, because it is assumed that you would be using previews of the .NET Core SDK. It is enabled by default.

[image]

### If you still don't see it...

The 'New Project' UI has changed, and if you're not used to it you might not notice where they put the new SDK version.

After 'Configure your project' where you give it a name, specify your repo file location and solution name, the next button will say 'CREATE'

A) If this is a .NET Core Console app, by default it will be using the latest SDK available, you'll need to right click on the project after it's created and edit the target framework if you need to. (or use `global.json`)

B) If this is an ASP.NET Core Web Application, the next screen has where you can pick the type of project (Api/Mvc/Etc..) and there is also a drop down where you can select the target framework, as well as a friendly text box which SDK it's targeting.

[image]